# Add a product to cart by selecting attributes in product list page - Prestashop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, prestashop

I want to display the product attributes in the product listing page.

And on clicking an attribute what I want is, I want to add that product with that particular attribute to the cart.

**For eg:** Suppose I'm having a product with color attribute and its values as red and blue. By default prestashop is having this feature to display the color. What I want is, if I click on Red color, the product with red color should be added to the cart through ajax and same for blue.

NB: I will be having only one attribute right now.